# I have written my affiliation in the incorrect format. Will the journal correct it after the paper is published or published online?

Tags: publications, online-publication

Unfortunately, I made a mistake in writing my academic affiliation (the format of my affiliation is incorrect: instead of **University of X**, I wrote **X University**), which makes my paper not to be accepted by the university. One of the papers with this incorrect format is published about 2 weeks ago and on of them has been published online. Will the journal correct it after the paper is published or published online if I send an email about this issue?

p.s., Unfortunately in my country (English is not the first language), the university does not accept my paper and I may lose my job. This wrong affiliation means I will lose almost 2 years of my attempt.

Comment: First, inform the editor(s) about the situation and about the importance of the problem.  Your "p.s." changes the picture greatly, so don't wait for the editor to think the error is minor.  Second, if the affiliations cannot be corrected and if your university administration can't be persuaded to be reasonable, then you may need the help of a lawyer.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Sure, I'll let them know about the importance of the issue. I desperately hope they will accept to change it.

Answer (score 6):

The journal isn't going to know about it and publish it exactly as you wrote it. If you want it fixed, you will need to tell them about it.

At the same time, the right approach is to just not worry about it. It is clear to everyone that "University of X" and "X University" are the same, in particular for universities in countries in which English is not the first language. In that case, the *actual* name of the university has to be translated anyway, and "University of X" and "X University" are both correct translations.

In other words, just let it be. The stating the affiliation of authors is intended to allow others to contact you. Whether they address a letter to "Kheeyal, University of X" or "Kheeyal, X University" doesn't matter: Both letters will find their way into your mailbox.

Comment: Thank you very much. But unfortunately in my country (English is not the first language), the university does not accept my paper and I may lose my job. This wrong affiliation means I will lose almost 2 years of my attempt.

Comment: Miami University is quite distinct from the University of Miami. The former is in Ohio and the latter in Florida.

Comment: @Kheeyal Well, that makes no sense at all. But if that's how it is, write to the editor-in-chief of the paper and explain the situation.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth - I have seen something similar. You can not claim to be familiar with the laws of all countries in the world. Some of them are weird and cruel.

Comment: Same with Washington University and the University of Washington, in Missouri and Washington, respectively.

Comment: There's also apparently a University of / Rochester / University in New York and Michigan.

Comment: Fair enough. I still think that a letter that also includes the city/state/zip code is going to find its way, and as such the misspelled affiliation should not lead to misunderstandings. But I get the point. I still think it's petty for administrators to be unwilling to count such publications, and I'm going to insist on that latter point: It's petty.

Comment: In countries with rampant bureaucracy, sorting out one such incident is easily thousands of taxpayers' dollars and the university is right in demanding attribution done properly. Otherwise it is just passing the issue on to the next person: the university may lose a big chunk of financing or fined for fraud when a semi-automated system or a bunch of clerks find this mismatch. It is rare that someone would take this burden upon themselves instead of scolding researchers. Thankfully, editors are usually forthcoming with such issues.